# Silverlight Organisation chart control

Tags: silverlight

Anyone know which control they used on this site to get the Organisation chart? http://www.yworks.com/products/yfilessilverlight/SilverChart.html
Or any other controls that are similiar?

If not, could you suggest a way on how to get started building one? (Interface-wise, I think I know how to get the data binding to work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The organisation chart control is their own, thats whole point of the demo page.

The UI elements involved are quite simple rectangular items.  The real trick is calculating their placement on panel and routing the connecting lines.

I guess the missing peice of the puzzle is what generically we would call that.  If you know that then you have a basis for a web search for algorithms for doing this sort of thing either academically or in some other product entirely, then bring that knowledge to your own Silverlight code.

Alternatively you could just go out buy the product.